# monerod v0.13.0.4 being killed / crashed randomly it seems

Tags: monerod

Below is the screenshot of when it got killed and also the bitmonero.log file.

I started monerod with the command:

**./monerod --block-sync-size 10**

What could the issue be?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To quote [@moneromooo-monero](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/4725):

> That's the OOM killer. Free more memory.

Comment: What is the minimum memory requirements? I'm guessing v13 uses more ram than v12 now?

Comment: If anything it uses _less_ RAM.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do next. Not sure how to "free more memory". My server is on centos.

Comment: Well how much RAM does your server have? How much swap space? Any other processes using high RAM?